# Silverlight Cross Domain Problems on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight, azure

I have 3 projects in my solution. A Silverlight project, a Web Project that hosts silverlight and provide some WCF services, and a third web project with some WCF services wich will be accessed by silverlight client.

In my client machine is working fine, as in production server. In my current production server I have both Server Web Apps hosted in the same domain, as different webapps.

The problem is that now we're trying to migrate the whole thing to azure. I've created two websites, one for each WebApp. So I have, lets say , the following address: 
MySLHostWebApp.azuresites.net
and
MyWCFServices.azuresites.net.

the silverlight application is running, and is accessing the services on MySLHostWebApp.azuresites.net correctly, buy when the Silverlight client tries to access MyWCFServices.azuresites.net, i have the following error:

```
An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 
'http://MyWCFServices.azuresites.net/MyService.svc'. This could be due to 
attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-
domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You 
may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy 
file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error 
may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without 
using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception 
for more details.
```

After searching the web about this, i found out i have to include a clientaccesspolicy.xml file in my WCF Service, to allow cross domain calls, but my service already have this file, with the following content:

```
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-methods="*">
        <domain uri="*" />
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource include-subpaths="true" path="/"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem. I was going to remove the question, but i'd rather leave the solution here, since other people could have the same problem.

The problem was that MyWCFServices.azuresites.net was mistakingly configured in azure to require AD authentication. Once I removed that requirement it worked fine. I still don't know thought why the unrelated error message.